# Unexpected base 64 decode result in Clojure

Tags: clojure, base64, clojure-contrib

I have required:

```
[clojure.data.codec.base64 :as b64]
```

I have defined a function:

```
(defn toHexString [bytes]
  "Convert bytes to a String"
  (apply str (map #(format "%x" %) bytes)))
```

I run this code to get a result in Clojure:

```
(toHexString (b64/decode (.getBytes "WR0frsVTzVg8QdA9l45/MuYZ3GUKGynDF7WaEYcjudI")))
```

I also run this code in PHP for comparison's sake (I am certain that the PHP result is correct):

```
echo bin2hex(base64_decode("WR0frsVTzVg8QdA9l45/MuYZ3GUKGynDF7WaEYcjudI"));
```

And I get these results for Clojure and PHP respectively:

```
591d1faec553cd583c41d03d978e7f32e619dc65a1b29c317b59a118723
591d1faec553cd583c41d03d978e7f32e619dc650a1b29c317b59a118723b9d2
```

Notice that the result is almost exactly the same. The only difference is the missing 0 in the middle and four missing characters at the end of the Clojure result.

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Is the base64 decode function in Clojure broken? Or what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `toHexString` needs to 0-pad for bytes that can be represented as a single hexadecimal number:

```
 (defn to-hex-string [bytes] (apply str (map #(format "%02x" %) bytes)))
```

Your base64 input has length of 43, so it is either needs to be padded out to a multiple of 4 or decoded with an implementation that does not require padding. Looks like PHP accepts non-padded input and this Clojure does not (truncates). Pad with "=".

```
(to-hex-string (b64/decode (.getBytes "WR0frsVTzVg8QdA9l45/MuYZ3GUKGynDF7WaEYcjudI=")))
```

This now gives the expected output.

Comment: Thanks! You've solved my headaches! Just a quick question though, how do you know to add an equal sign at the end?

Comment: @ibopm The doc-string for decode specifies input length must be in multiples of 4. The `=` padding is standard when padding is used, so I just tried it.

Comment: this might be asking too much, but would you mind showing me an example of how I can make a function that would check if a string input length is a multiple of 4, and if it's not then pad it with "=" until it is?

I'm really new to functional programming and would really appreciate an example, thanks! I can create a new question for this if you'd prefer.

Comment: `(defn pad-to-multiple [s m pad] (apply str s (repeat (mod (- 0 (count s)) m) pad)))`